# Scoped properties for Application Insights

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I would like to know if there is an elegant way to add *scoped properties* to Application Insights, something similar to `Serilog`:

```
var yearEnricher = new PropertyEnricher("Year", year);

using (LogContext.PushProperties(yearEnricher))
{
    // ...
}
```

In the previous example every log created within the `using` block will have the property `Year` stamped on it.

I figured out how to do this when I want the property to be present within the whole request pipeline:

```
var requestTelemetry = context.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
requestTelemetry?.Properties.Add(propertyName, propertyValue.ToString());
```

Sometimes I want to create a *logging scope* in code that is not related to the web context so it doesn't make sense to rely on the `IHttpContextAccessor`. I acknowledge I could leverage `OperationTelemetry` and `TelemetryClient.StartOperation` to achieve my goal but it is cumbersome as I've to implement a few properties in which I've no interest (such as `Name`, `Success`, `Duration`...).

Is there a better way than relying on `OperationTelemetry`?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `OperationTelemetry`, you might want to look into implementing your own `ITelemetryInitializer` (see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling)).
It should be fairly easy to implement a stack-like global structure to hold the properties you want to push, and pop the stack on your `Dispose` method.

Note that you'll probably need to utilize `CallContext` in order for your stacks to be thread safe.